# Making a new list with tuples based on strings in the list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
L = ["5", "0 1", "0 2", "1 3", "2 3", "2 4", "3 4"]
```

Each number represents a person. So, there are five people from 0 to 4 in the list. `L[0]` always shows how many people are in the list.

```
L1 = [(0,[1,2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3,4]), (3, [4])]
```

The person `"0"` is paired with `1` and `2`. So, it has a list of `1, 2` in a tuple. My approach to get the result above is to compare the first character in `L[1]` to the end of the list. If the first letter in `L[1]` matches with the first letter in `L[2]`, it bundles the second letter in `L[2]` with the second letter in `L[1]`. Finally, the new list is paired with `0` in a tuple. By the way, I cannot come up with such thing that can check the first letter in strings. I am not sure if this approach is right or not.

I am struggling to make such list `L1` above. Could anyone let me know if my approach to this question is right? If it is wrong, please briefly give me a hint to solve this.

Comment: I am not supposed to use dictionary. If possible, could you explain it with list?

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

Created a list in the required range, considering `L[0]`

Checks for matches between the element and the other items using `startswith`

```
L = ["5", "0 1", "0 2", "1 3", "2 3", "2 4", "3 4"]
L1 = [(0,[1,2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3,4]), (3, [4])]     # required list

L2 = [ (i, [ int(x[-1]) for x in L if str(x).startswith(str(i)) ]) for i in range(int(L[0])-1) ]
```

Output

```
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [4])]
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing is to first use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice

result = defaultdict(list)

for li in islice(L,1,None):
    h, *others = map(int,li.split())
    for other in others:
        result[h].append(other)
```

Or a version that works for [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice

result = defaultdict(list)

for li in islice(L,1,None):
    data = map(int,li.split())
    h = data[0]
    for other in data[1:]:
        result[h].append(other)
```

and then we obtain the `items` of that dictionary:

```
L1 = list(result.items())
```

This produces:

```
>>> L1
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [4])]
```

Note that in this case the items are *not* ordered: since a dictionary in Python usually has no order (the latest implementations in CPython have, but this is seen as an implementation detail).

But converting the dictionary back into a list is not logical, since the advantage of a dictionary is a fast lookup (in *O(1)*, constant time).

We can make the last part more elegant by writing:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for li in islice(L,1,None):
    h, *others = map(int,li.split())
    result[h] += others
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `*others`.  Couldn't you just use `L1[1:]` to avoid the problematic first element?  OP doesn't suggest any sublists of more then 2 "elements".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list, go with dict and use this pattern without importing any external module.

```
L = ["5", "0 1", "0 2", "1 3", "2 3", "2 4", "3 4"]

final_dict={}
new=[]
for item in L:
    if not len(item)<2:
        if int(item[0]) not in final_dict:
            final_dict[int(item[0])]=[int(item[2])]
        else:
            final_dict[int(item[0])].append(int(item[2]))

print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4]}
```

or if you want the result in the list then add this line end of above code:

```
print([(key,value) for key,value in final_dict.items()])
```

output:

```
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a form of `dictionary` for easier processing of the data later on. So here, `defualtdict` would be best utilized.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> L = ["5", "0 1", "0 2", "1 3", "2 3", "2 4", "3 4"]
>>> n  = int(L.pop(0))                                    #number of people

>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for ele in L: 
        x, y  = map(int, ele.split()) 
        d[x].append(y)    

>>> d
=> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1, 2], 1: [3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4]})
```

If neccessary to have that `list` format, use `dict.items()` and type cast it to `list`

```
>>> l1 = list(d.items())
>>> l1
=> [(0, [1, 2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [4])]
```

Comment: This will not always work, since some elements are orphans (like `"5"`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : the OP says `L[0] always shows how many people are in the list.` . That '5' there is the number of persons.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `l1 = d.items()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `itertools.groupy` solution. (The commented out line also considers reverse pairs.)

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

def L1(L):
    # split pairs
    L = [p.split() for p in L[1:]]
    # convert to int
    L = [(int(P1), int(P2)) for P1, P2 in L]
    LL = sorted(L)
#    # add reversed and sort
#    LL = sorted(L + [P[::-1] for P in L])
    # group by first element
    res = it.groupby(LL, op.itemgetter(0))
    # make proper lists
    return [(k, [P[1] for P in v]) for k, v in res]
```

Output (for the example `L`):

```
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [3]), (2, [3, 4]), (3, [4])]
```